# blazor scoped service initializing twice

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to learn asp.net core, more specifically blazor server. From the documentation, it appears a service registered as scoped will be created once per connection. My user service constructor is running twice on the first load of the page in the browser, and twice again on each refresh of the page.

I believe these are the applicable parts of the code necessary to help me determine why this is occurring. My question is how to make it create one instance of the user service for each client connection? I'm getting the correct output on screen but don't prefer it to run twice.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddDbContext<AWMOPSContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AWMOPSContext")),
        ServiceLifetime.Transient);
    services.AddScoped<UserService>();

}
```

```
public class UserService
{
    public Associate Associate { get; set; }

    public UserService(AWMOPSContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        var username = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(7);
        Associate = context.Associates.Where(a => a.LogonName == username).FirstOrDefault();
        Debug.WriteLine($"Hello {Associate.PreferredName} {Associate.LastName}");
    }
}
```

```
@page "/"
@inject AWMWP.Services.UserService user;

<h1>Welcome @user.Associate.PreferredName @user.Associate.LastName</h1>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is called twice, as you are using pre-rendering. Go to `_Host.cshtml` and change `render-mode="ServerPrerendered"` to `render-mode="Server"`, and it would be called only once:

```
<app>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
</app>
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering