# Why are Blazor lifecycle methods getting executed twice? what is the benefit of this feature?

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, matblazor

Why are Blazor lifecycle methods getting executed twice?
what is the benefit of this feature?

Comment: <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

Comment: Can you share some code, what is getting executed twice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are Blazor lifecycle methods getting executed twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075628/why-are-blazor-lifecycle-methods-getting-executed-twice)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/60996170/60761

Answer (score 2):

They are executed twice because your application is pre-rendering. Note that while your application is pre-rendering JavaScript is not available. To opt for pre-rendering, set the render-mode attribute of the component Html tag helper to "ServerPrerendered", like the following:

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

If you don't want pre-rendering, set the render-mode attribute to `"Server"`

That was the short answer. If you want a full-blown description as to why you need pre-rendering, what consideration you should take into account, etc., look up the subject in the [docs...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#render-mode)